# Wait until statement is completed

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sqlite, air

I'd like to write a function, which will be look like this:

```
public function execute(sql:String) {
        sessionDBConn.open(writeSessionDB);

        createStmt.sqlConnection = sessionDBConn; 
        createStmt.text = sql; 

        createStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, onResult); 
        createStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, onError); 

        createStmt.execute(); 
    }
```

And I want this function to wait until SQLLite statement is done. All I have now is that onResult is invoked, when executing of statement is completed, but code, when I execute `execute(sql)` move on to the next line immediately.

What can I do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are asynchronous, and as such, you cannot halt all other code execution while waiting for a response.

One solution would be to refactor your code so that all code that follows the call to `execute` is called from within your `onResult` method.

You could also implement some form of callback framework, such that your `execute` method would accept a second paramater of type `Function`:

```
public function execute(sql:String, callback:Function) {
    sessionDBConn.open(writeSessionDB);

    createStmt.sqlConnection = sessionDBConn; 
    createStmt.text = sql; 

    createStmt.addEventListener(SQLEvent.RESULT, callback); 
    createStmt.addEventListener(SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, onError); 

    createStmt.execute(); 
}
```

Then, you could place all relevant code in whatever method you pass to the `execute` method.